# How do I retrieve a JSON parameter with into an NSArray/NSDictionary

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, xcode, json

I need help here.

This is my JSON webservice http://webservice.creaworld.sg/vesselservice.ashx?test.

Select the method **getdatasetmem_serialize** notice that the JSON data has a backslash or escape char in it.

Why is this happening?, and how do I retrieve the value in, lets say, the `i_member_id` in Xcode? I know that the retrieved JSON data "Table" is an Array and it has 2 dictionaries in it.

Comment: The serialised versions provided by that Web service are JSON (or C) strings containing JSON data, hence why they’re escaped. Can’t you use the non-serialised versions?

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to parse serialized response? Can you parse normal JSON?

```
NSError *error;

NSDictionary *json = [parser objectWithString:content error:&error];
if ( json == nil ) {
    UIAlertView *errorAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
        initWithTitle:@"Error"
        message:[error localizedDescription]
        delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];
        [errorAlert show];
        [errorAlert autorelease];
} else {
    NSArray *trends = [json objectForKey:@"trends"];
    for (NSDictionary *trend in trends) {
        [viewController.names addObject:[trend objectForKey:@"name"]];
        [viewController.urls addObject:[trend objectForKey:@"url"]];
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Guys the answer doesn't work, i am still unable to retrieve the objectforkeyvalue, found another  json service example on the web http://www.raboof.com/Projects/Jayrock/demo.ashx? go the the "getdataset" method how do i retrieve the employee firstname, lastname and etc??